# Php artisan serve with error auth

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, composer-php

i just update to laravel 5.2 and then i try to use php artisan serve

just error like

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php on line 146
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]   Class
>   'App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider' not found

i am very confuse for that

Answer (score 2):

Look for this class, if it's exists, try to run `composer dumpauto`.

If you don't have this class, try to install Laravel again. It seems your Laravel installation is incomplete, Try to install it again. I have fresh Laravel 5.2.31 installation and the file is there.

Comment: i am try to run php artisan make:auth but it same error

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php on line 146


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider' not found

Comment: It seems your Laravel installation is incomplete, Try to install it again. I have fresh Laravel 5 installation and the file is there. First, try to run `comoser update`, maybe it'll reinstall corrupted/missing files.

Answer (score 0):

try running following commands and try again,

```
composer du     //or the second one if this one does not work
composer update
```